# Check if an object sees another object in a specified field of view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a small sheep and fox simulation in unity. I want to check if the fox can see the sheep from an adjustable field of view. I don't know where to start for this.

Could someone please suggest a starting point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you would consider in view. But here is a snippet that should only pass the conditional when the fox can see the sheep in view of 180º in front of them.

```
// get the direction we are facing 
Vector3 targetDir = sheep.position - fox.position;

// returns the angle (from, to)
float angleToSheep = Vector3.Angle(targetDir, transform.forward);

// when the angle is at -90 or +90, then it is in view (180º FOV)
if (angleToSheep >= -90 && angleToSheep <= 90)
    Debug.Log("Sheep in sight!");
```

[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html) is the Vector3.Angle docs in case you want to read up on them.